# Run solr in schemaless mode

Tags: solr

I try to run solr in schemaless mode on a windows machine, like it is described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schemaless+Mode). But if I run the command

```
java -Dsolr.solr.home=example-schemaless\solr -jar start.jar
```

I get the error:

```
Could not find or load main class .solr.home=example-schemaless.solr
```

Answer (score 1):

check the path of your start.jar file. Make the correct path to start.jar file and set the solr home correctly, that may be fix your issue.

Comment: My start path is `C:\solr-4.6.1\example>` and the command `java -jar start.jar` starts solr ordinary under the default `Dsolr.solr.home`.

Comment: Try the following command and see what will you get:

java -Dsolr.solr.home=solr-4.6.1\example -jar start.jar

Comment: Same issue. I downloaded solr by this [tutorial](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_1/tutorial.html), there is no hint how to set solr home.

Comment: I don't know what are you using tomcat or jetty? but for tomcat here is the [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat). you can set solr home and try.

Comment: Of curse I use the download Jetty (http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/solr/4.6.1) because it is given by the tutorial I linked before.

Comment: Till now I could not see what Iam doing wrong by starting solr for schemaless mode.